# Setting setter of an interface in class implementing it

Tags: interface, kotlin

Just begin with using kotlin in android-

I am trying to use setter of an interface in a class implementing it-

```
interface MyInterface {
    val prop: Int // abstract

var propertyWithImplementation: String
    get() = "foo"
set(text){"$text foo"}

fun foo() {
    print(prop)
}

}

class Child : MyInterface {
    override val prop: Int = 29
 override var propertyWithImplementation="bhu"

}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Child().propertyWithImplementation)
}
```

Output:bhu

Expected Output=bhu foo

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *overriding* the `var`, not setting it, and not using the parent setter in the override, so it ends up not being used in any way. Setting it would look like e.g.

```
class Child : MyInterface {
    override val prop: Int = 29
    init {
        propertyWithImplementation="bhu"
    }
}
```

but if you do that the output will be `foo` because that's what the getter *always* returns. And the setter doesn't actually set anything, it just creates a string and ignores it.

You don't have backing fields in an interface, so you'll need to store the value somewhere else, e.g.

```
interface MyInterface {
    protected var backingProperty: String

    var propertyWithImplementation: String
        get() = backingProperty
        set(text){ backingProperty = "$text foo" }
}

class Child {
    override var backingProperty = "foo"
}
```

to fix this problem.

Comment: thanks..how will i return the setted string from getter?

Comment: println(Child().propertyWithImplementation) gives output "foo".Expected output "foo foo"

Comment: In the example code? You'll only get `foo foo` after you _set_ `propertyWithImplementation = "foo"`.

Comment: It seems that what you really want is to override the _getter_, not the setter. You should be able to figure out how.